# What does, "FATAL: Error computing merge base" mean?

Tags: git, jenkins

I've had Jenkins running for about a year now.  It builds master, rc*, and production branches.  On every commit, it performs a git clone, does a bundle install, runs a migration, etc.  It's been working perfectly.  Recently, it has been failing and I'm getting the following traceback:

```
FATAL: Error computing merge base
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error computing merge base
  at hudson.plugins.git.util.GitUtils.filterTipBranches(GitUtils.java:149)
  at hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser.getAdvancedCandidateRevisions(DefaultBuildChooser.java:201)
  at hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser.getCandidateRevisions(DefaultBuildChooser.java:46)
  at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1057)
  at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:948)
  at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2417)
  at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
  at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
  at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
  at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

With the following displayed immediately after:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing commit 2faf546491565d033b1e0a79bef4b2d107447f49
  at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:149)
  at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.getCachedBytes(RevWalk.java:853)
  at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit.parseHeaders(RevCommit.java:142)
  at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.MergeBaseGenerator.next(MergeBaseGenerator.java:148)
  at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.StartGenerator.next(StartGenerator.java:102)
  at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.next(RevWalk.java:414)
  at hudson.plugins.git.util.GitUtils.filterTipBranches(GitUtils.java:127)
  ... 14 more
```

This commit error is also confusing since all branches include it.

What exactly does, "Error computing merge base mean?" and why am I getting the missing commit message?

Any insights here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

git fsck:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (3203/3203), done.
```

In my Jenkins configuration, my git plugin config is set to:

> 1. Wipe out workspace before build
> 2. Use shallow clone

I'm using Jenkins, ver. 1.528.

Comment: Seems your local repo got corrupted. Any strange output from `git fsck`? Also, are your remotes correctly (pls verify by hand). Another thing is to set Jenkins to clean up the workspace before pulling (i.e., to drop all local changes). There was a setting for that in the project configuration.

Comment: you should tag this with jenkins imho

Comment: Have you always used shallow cloning? I would think that, depending on  exactly how shallow a clone is, finding a merge base of two branches (which is essentially the most recent commit that both have in common, or the point where the two branches diverge) might be difficult. Perhaps you have just never run into a situation before where you had two branches whose merge base was sufficiently deep to get pruned by the shallow clone...

Comment: I turned off shallow clone.  It looks like my branch built this time.  Going to keep it off for a bit, see if this reoccurs.  If it doesn't, I'll close with disabling shadow clone being the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per twalberg's comment above, disabling shallow clone solved this issue.  All branches built and jobs completed.

Comment: You need to do both actions:
Enable: Wipe out workspace before build,
Disable: Use shallow clone

Comment: Please can you share the steps?